# How to write inner join Query with SUM in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have two Queries

```
SELECT PId,
       COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM Bill_Entry
GROUP BY PId
ORDER BY Quantity DESC

SELECT SUM(CAST(Quantity AS FLOAT)) AS TotalSalesQuantity,
       SUM(CAST(Total AS FLOAT)) AS TotalSalesAmount
FROM Bill_Entry
WHERE ProductId = pi
```

Both are same table. How to join this query?

Comment: I'm not getting your question. What you want as a result? Why you want to join this two query?

Comment: One of your queries contains a filter.  The other doesn't.  Is this intentional?  If you could provide sample records and expected output I'm sure we can find an answer.

Comment: You will also find people are more likely to help you if you [accept their answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Looking at your history I can see you have five open questions.

Comment: give an example output format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT PId,
       MAX(TotalSalesQuantity),
       MAX(TotalSalesAmount),
       COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM (
    SELECT PId,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ProductId = @pi THEN Quantity * 1. END) OVER () AS TotalSalesQuantity,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ProductId = @pi THEN Total * 1. END) OVER () AS TotalSalesAmount
    FROM Bill_Entry
) t
GROUP BY PId
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```